# Vue recognize text pattern and replace by href to correct resource

Tags: vue.js, tags, vue-router

I'm working on a project where I keep a log of key actions by users. For example a log entry is made when a user logs in to the application. I use a Laravel API as backend that takes care of the logging the event in the database and takes care of retrieving log entries to be displayed in the application. An example of a log entry returned for display is the following:

`{{user|123|"John Doe"}} logged in at 2020-01-03 11:00:05`

Now, I'd like Vue to automatically recognize that this should be replaced by the following:

`<router-link to="/user/123">John Doe</router-link> logged in at 2020-01-03 11:00:05`

So it automatically becomes a clickable link that navigates to the user profile in this case.

Does Vue offer any such functionality? Any ideas on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can bind to `to` a computed property that will build the path string or data property (then you need to save the builded path in a data section when receving your response):

Template:
`<router-link :to="path">{{userName}}</router-link>`

script:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            path: '',
            userName: ''   
        }
    },
    // OR
    computed: {
        path() {
            <build your path from entry variable>
            return <your builded path>
        },
        userName() {
            <extract your user name>
            return <extracted user name>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put the script you suggested?

Comment: Check out this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html and this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
    <router-link :to="user.path">{{user.name}}</router-link>
    logged in at {{ user.loginTime }}
</div>
```

I think I will use a v-for to do this, I am wondering what data you got from your Ajax api ?